# No difference between nullable:true and nullable:false in Grails 1.3.6?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The following domain model definition ..

```
class Test {
  String a
  String b

  static mapping = {
    version(false)
    table("test_table")
    a(nullable: false)
    b(nullable: true)
  }
}
```

.. yields the following MySQL schema ..

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  a varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  b varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please note that `a` and `b` get identical MySQL column definitions despite the fact `a` is defined as non-nullable and `b` is nullable in the GORM mappings.

What am I doing wrong? I'm running Grails 1.3.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nullable true/false goes in the `static constraints` closure, not in the `static mapping`.  See the [constraints section](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) of the Grails documentation.